# Custom Validator Angular 2 - Get Return

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, validation, typescript, angular

So, i need get the value from return of my validator.

Example: {'emailValidation':'email is invalid.'}

Key = emailValidation

Value = email is invalid.

Can i use this value in my HTML Code?

```
validate(c: Control): { [key: string]: any } {

    if (c.value == undefined) {
        return null;
    }

    var emailReg = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return emailReg.test(c.value) ? null : { 'emailValidation': 'email is invalid.' };
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the control and its `errors` attribute this way:

```
<form [formGroup]="someForm">
  <input  formControlName="someCtrl" />
  <div *ngIf="someCtrl.errors">
    <div *ngIf="someCtrl.errors.emailValidation">
      {{someCtrl.errors.emailValidation}}
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```